# using Mule to connect MongoDB

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, collections, mule, anypoint-studio

I have fetched some of my SQLServer database tables using Mule and now i need to create a collection into mongoDB.

I am able to create successful connections but not able to create the collection into MongoDB.

below is the XML which i am using for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd">
<db:generic-config name="MicrosoftSQLServerDB"         url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=TESTNAV;user=sa;password=xxxxx" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
<mongo:config name="mymongoconfig"   database="mydb1" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="replicateFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:select config-ref="MicrosoftSQLServerDB" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[Select * from [Electoral-Mechanicals P Ltd$Customer]]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <logger message="No. of Records fetched from Table:#[payload.size()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mongo:insert-object  collection="customer" config-ref="mymongoconfig" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Even the Application status is deployed after running the application but there's no collection in MongoDB

---

- - - - APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *

        ---
- replicate                                     * default                        * DEPLOYED           *

  ---

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly create a collection. You can use the below details/example to create a new collection.

> **Create Collection**
>
> ```
> '<mongo:create-collection>'
> ```
>
> Creates a new collection. If the collection already exists, a
>   MongoException is thrown.
>
> **XML Sample**
>
> ```
> <mongo:create-collection 
> config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration"             
> collection="aCollection" capped="true"/>
> ```

Alternatively,

if you decide to check first that a collection exist with same name and you dont want to mess up anything. You can use the following :

> **Exists Collection**
>
> ```
> <mongo:exists-collection>
> ```
>
> Answers if a collection exists given its name
>   **XML Sample**
>
> ```
> <mongo:exists-collection 
> config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" 
> collection="aColllection"/>
> ```

Comment: Hi Satish, Thanks for the response.... I have already created the database and collection manually into _mongoDB_ with the same name as i used in my code. but things are still the same .. there's no data reflecting into mongoDB under the **customer** collection

Comment: can you use <mongo:exists-collection> to make sure your code is able to poll/reach the collection you created.

Comment: are you getting any error or is it that your code just executes fine but nothing get inserted into the collection.

Comment: to insert a document, i guess you need to user insert-document tag. <mongo:insert-document config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="Employees">
</mongo:insert-document> please use this and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: actually i dont see any API called <mongo:insert-object> to insert documents to the mongodb you need to use <mongo:insert-document>

Comment: Hi Satish, Actually I am using Anypoint Studio for this and there are operations to be incorporated into mogoDB. I am available with only InsertObject and not insertdocument with mongo.

Comment: ok i have anypoint studio installed on my laptop. i will try to simulate and let you know. but from the official API page for mule-mongo there is no insert:object .

Answer (score 0):

To insert documents to collection in mongodb using mule you need

```
<mongo:insert-document 
config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" 
collection="Employees"> </mongo:insert-document>
```

however you are using

```
<mongo:insert-object> which i guess is not a valid API entity,
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the version that  you have, you need to use InsertObject or InsertDocument. Most operation names have been changed to comply with Mongo Driver v3, so if you had an InsertObject operation, it now appears as InsertDocument.

In any case, to invoke insertDocument operation, follow these steps in Mule:

1. Locate, and drag and drop the HTTP connector, Transform Message, and MongoDB connector onto the Anypoint Studio Canvas.
2. Configure the MongoDB connector by selecting the Connector Configuration and choose the operation "InsertDocument" to invoke it
3. Click Transform Message and enter the key values that you want to insert

Comment: Hi @andrescortes  , the version I am using for Anypoint and mongoDB driver there's no option for "InsertDocument". I am available with "Insert-Object " option only. Please advice.